# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Why?

Tags: javascript, string, syntax-error, identifier

I get a **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Error** in this line:

```
if(v=="ZP31"||v=="ZC31"||v=="SX31"||v=="SX71"||v=="SW71"||v=="XM71"||v=="1Z21"){return "<span class="label label-default">Default</span>";}
```

Which identifier is missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Also note that if your `if` statement is not inside of a `function` you will get an error like this in Chrome for example **SyntaxError: Illegal return statement**. 
`return` statement can only be used inside of a `function`.

Answer (score 2):

Your string nesting is incorrect.

Either you escape the double quotes,

```
return "<span class=\"label label-default\">Default</span>";
```

or change to single quotes:

```
return '<span class="label label-default">Default</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must just escape your HTML return string like this :

```
"<span class=\"label label-default\">Default</span>"
```